# Require a Listener class for RabbitMQ Channel shutdown exceptions happens in Spring stream applications

Tags: spring, rabbitmq, spring-amqp, spring-cloud-stream, spring-cloud-dataflow

We are using spring cloud data flow stream applications and RabbitMQ as a message broker.

In overall stream flow from source to sink modules , we are loosing data when ever we see "ChannelShutdown : connection errors" occurred in any of modules in a given stream flow.

`Stream Example: Source | Transformer1 | transformer2 | transformer3 | sink`

i.e. Any of the RabbitMQ channels connects were lost then Applications were failing to transmit the data to next modules/Applications which leads to data loss.

Exceptions :

```
2019-02-18 15:29:41.364 ERROR 94489 --- [ 127.0.0.1:5672] o.s.a.r.c.CachingConnectionFactory       : Channel shutdown: connection error; 
2019-02-18 15:29:42.008  INFO 94489 --- [strationQueue-1] o.s.a.r.l.SimpleMessageListenerContainer : Restarting Consumer@6adc5b9c: tags=[{amq.ctag-5dNneAd3QgwWADta7JAmQQ=employeeRegistrations.employeeRegistrationQueue}], channel=Cached Rabbit Channel: AMQChannel(amqp://guest@127.0.0.1:5672/,1), conn: Proxy@a6e4897 Shared Rabbit Connection: SimpleConnection@22dc59b2 [delegate=amqp://guest@127.0.0.1:5672/, localPort= 50775], acknowledgeMode=NONE local queue size=0
2019-02-18 15:29:42.010  INFO 94489 --- [strationQueue-2] o.s.a.r.c.CachingConnectionFactory       : Attempting to connect to: [localhost:5672]
2019-02-18 15:29:42.019  INFO 94489 --- [strationQueue-2] o.s.a.r.c.CachingConnectionFactory       : Created new connection: rabbitConnectionFactory#d611f1c:1/SimpleConnection@1782b48a [delegate=amqp://guest@127.0.0.1:5672/, localPort= 50864]
```

---

To replicate the issue : 
I ran two spring cloud stream programs

1. Producer - Which pushes 100,000 messages  to RabbitMQ exchange
2. Consumer - Which is sink module receives payload from that queue [linked to exchange ]and prints

In order to get "channel shutdown : connection error" in consumer program logs , I went to rabbitMQ UI page and  continuously removed the connections available in RabbitMQ UI page.

[image]

finally, During this process , consumer received only 98,484 messages out of 100,000 messages. So we lost data in transit due to channels connection shutdown

---

**My Question :**

**Can we catch or detect the "Channel shutdown: Connection Error" in Spring stream applications ?**

**Is there any RabbitMQ listener class available to include in stream application to handle the error "Channel shutdown: Connection Error" ?**

I came across RabbitMQ listeners like

using @RabbitListener Annotation inside Stream application

```
Example:
@RabbitListener(queues = TEST_QUEUE)
    public void handle(Foo in) {
        logger.info("Received: " + in);
    }
```

but This RabbitMQ listener listens to only specified queues or binding as specified in definition https://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp/api/org/springframework/amqp/rabbit/annotation/RabbitListener.html

> I would like to know is there any common RabbitMQ listener class which
>   listens  to channel connections instead of listening to specific
>   queue.
>
> So my question is like are there any Listeners available to check any
>   channels [ linked to present application ] shutdown happened or not if
>   so I can handle the data loss by sending payload back to next
>   application after channel connection established.

Does **SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory class** help me in this situation ? if so please let me know the approach to solve this data loss issue due to channel shutdowns and connection loss issue.

Example:

Comment: Your question is not at all clear. "`@RabbitListener` expects queue and binder " - I don't know what that means; edit the question to include more information about your issue, including configuration and code.

Comment: I corrected my question. Please let me know if you need further information on the question which I am asking

Answer (score 0):

You can enable retry in the producer with Spring Boot properties. [Documentation here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/common-application-properties.html).

Scroll down to RabbitMQ

```
...
spring.rabbitmq.template.retry.enabled=false # Whether publishing retries are enabled.
spring.rabbitmq.template.retry.initial-interval=1000ms # Duration between the first and second attempt to deliver a message.
spring.rabbitmq.template.retry.max-attempts=3 # Maximum number of attempts to deliver a message.
spring.rabbitmq.template.retry.max-interval=10000ms # Maximum duration between attempts.
spring.rabbitmq.template.retry.multiplier=1 # Multiplier to apply to the previous retry interval.
...
```

But, to answer your question, you can add a `ConnectionListener` to the connection factory bean definition.

Comment: You can, however, add a `ConnectionListener`.